# Get parent's BUILD_NUMBER from child script in Hudson

Tags: hudson

I am configuring a Hudson job with a shell script. It is possible to get the current job number from the environment variable 'BUILD_NUMBER'. I was wondering if it was also possible to get the number of the 'parent' (i.e. the job that triggered the current job), or to check if the current job was triggered manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default Hudson doesn't have any Environment variable which contains Parent Job's build number.

You can use [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).

This plugins allows you to configure the child jobs and provides additional Env variables which can be used by the child jobs. You can also provide the Parent jobs build number to child jobs using this plugin.

**TRIGGERED_BUILD_NUMBER_project name** is a Env variable provided by the plugin which contains the last build number of the **"project name"** . **project name** can be your Parent job name.